Optimal order to attack enemies in a game
Let's say you're being attacked by a group of enemies, each of which does a different amount of damage per second, and will take you a different amount of seconds to kill.
The goal is to find in which order you should attack them to minimize the damage received at the end.
Now here's my theory:

First add up the time to kill all of them
Then, for each enemy, find how much damage you'll be spared by killing them first, as follows: (timeToKillAll - enemy.timeToKill) * enemy.damageRate
Always attack the enemy which gives the largest result

Is this the right answer?

With optimization problems like this, what I often do is code a simple brute force solution first so I have something to check the results of a more sophisticated algorithm against. If you have n enemies, you have n! ways of ordering their deaths. For small n values, you can just check them all.

I would cast a spell on them first, so they are stunned. I would also cast a spell on myself such that whoever hits me, gets damage from that action themselves. I would also cast a few pets that do some damage themselves. Apply any health boosters before entering into combat. Oh, but if you have a programming question, then please provide code that initialises the inputs, and provides the mechanics.

For larger n, I suspect there's an efficient way to tackle this using dynamic programming.

This problem seems to be 1|r_i=0|\Sum w_i C_i in scheduling notation.

"In 1956, Smith [14] showed that, in the absence of precedence
constraints, an optimal solution could be found by sequencing the jobs in
nondecreasing order of the ratios wj/pj. This can, of course, be done in
0(n log n) running time." --Eugene Lawler. Sequencing jobs to minimize total weighted completion time subject to precedence
constraints. Research Report, IRIA-RR-205, IRIA. 1976, pp.27. hal-04716371 which says that you can simply do the greedy algorithm of hitting enemy with highest ratio enemy.damageRate/enemy.timeToKill first.
